# Как в git получить файлы из текущей ветки, которые отличаются от мастер-ветки?

Tags: git

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в git получить файлы (сами файлы, а не список), которые в данной ветке отличаются от файлов мастер ветки.

Работаем с bitbucket, там можно получить список файлов, жаль, что нельзя выгрузить их архивом.

Answer (score 5):

Для выгрузки архивов из git используется команда `git archive`. Для поиска изменённых или добавленных файлов можно использовать `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=...`.

Пример получения архива с файлами, отличающимися в текущей версии от master:

```
git  diff -z --diff-filter=ACMR --name-only master HEAD | xargs -0r git archive HEAD > myarchive.tar
```

Проблемы примера:

- Символические ссылки могут обрабатываться неправильно
- Удалённые файлы не обрабатываются
- Если будет слишком много файлов, `git archive` вызовется несколько раз, "склеив" архивы.

Comment: Хорошие ответы у вас. Почаще, что ли, пишите.